# Не работает сжатие, node express.js + compression

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Server js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    compression = require('compression'), 
    app = express();

app.use(compression()); 
app.use(express.static(rootDir));
```

В запросе: `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch`
В ответе отсутcтвует: `Content-encoding: gzip`

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А какой файл запрашиваете? Какие данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе с модулем `compression` нужно помнить о двух тонких моментах:

1. Если тело ответа меньше значения, указанного в параметре [`threshold`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression#threshold), то ответ **не будет** сжиматься. Это позволяет экономить ресурсы сервера в случаях, когда сжатие не даст существенного выигрыша клиенту. По умолчанию, `compression` использует значение `1kb`.
2. Не все файлы должны сжиматься. Например, применение сжатия к файлам `image/png`, в ряде случаев, может увеличить их размер. В модуле `compression` существует параметр [`filter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression#filter). Значением этого параметра является функция, определяющая необходимость сжатия ответа. По умолчанию используется модуль `compressible`, который разрешает сжатие только для текстовых файлов (с mime-типами `text/*` и `application/json`).

Таким образом, если вы **действительно** хотите сжимать *все* ответы сервера, вам нужно использовать вот такой код:

```
var express = require('express'),
    compression = require('compression'), 
    app = express();

app.use(compression({
    // Сжимаем HTTP ответы, тело которых длиннее одного байта
    threshold: 1,
    // Сжимаем HTTP ответы независимо от их mime-типа
    filter: function() {return true;}
})); 
app.use(express.static(rootDir));
```